# SonarScanner is configured in Jenkins Tools, but '${scannerHome}' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

i'm tring to use SonarQube inside my Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline{
    agent any 
    stages{
        stage('build'){
            steps{
                // invoke command to build with maven
                bat 'mvn clean install'
            }
        }

        stage('SonarQube') {
            environment {
                scannerHome = tool 'SonarQubeScanner'
            }
            steps {
                withSonarQubeEnv('SonarQube') { 
                    bat '${scannerHome}/bin/sonar-scanner.bat'
                }
            }
         }
    }
}
```

this is my SonarQube server
[image: SonarQube]

and this is SonarScanner

[image: sonarScanner]

what is wrong with `withSonarQubeEnv` step:

```
withSonarQubeEnv('SonarQube') { 
    bat '${scannerHome}/bin/sonar-scanner.bat'
}
```

that I always got an error

> '${scannerHome}' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: Could you try with double quotes instead ? Also does the path to sonarqube contain spaces in the path ? Maybe then you might have to use specific  escape characters.

Comment: same problem , the error is      
null/bin/sonar-scanner.bat  'null' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

how can Jenkins figure out what is ${scannerHome} while i use "Install automatically" in SonarQube Scanner installations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two problems:

1. you didn't add any installer to `SonarQubeScanner` tool (only checkbox is checked)
2. the code is incorrect

---

Single quotes are not evaluated (treat as is). It means that:

```
def value = 'ABC'
println '${value}/bin/sonar-scanner.bat'
```

prints `${value}/bin/sonar-scanner.bat`. You have to use double quotes:

```
def value = 'ABC'
println "${value}/bin/sonar-scanner.bat"
```

prints `ABC/bin/sonar-scanner.bat`.

The code should be equal to:

```
withSonarQubeEnv('SonarQube') { 
    bat "${scannerHome}/bin/sonar-scanner.bat"
}
```